# Decoding a Google protocol buffer message in javascript using ProtoBuf.js

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers

I am trying to send a message over MQTT making use of the google protocol buffer in javascript (ProtoBuf.js)

I was able to encode the message using the following code:

```
var ProtoBuf = dcodeIO.ProtoBuf;
var builder = ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile("./complex.proto"),
Game = builder.build("Game"),
Car = Game.Cars.Car;
var car = new Car({
"model" : "Rusty",
"vendor" : {
            "name" : "Iron Inc.",
           "address" : {
                "country" : "USa"
             }
          },
    "speed" : "FAST"
 });
 var buffer = car.encode();
console.log(buffer);
var messagegpb = buffer.toBuffer();
console.log(messagegpb ); //This prints "ArrayBuffer { byteLength: 29 }"
```

Now for decoding when I tried the following, it just doesn't do anything. I see no logs in the browser as well.

```
var dec = builder.build("Game"); //nothing after this line gets executed
var msg = dec.decode(messagegpb);
console.log(msg);
```

This is the link of the .proto file I am using. https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/blob/master/tests/complex.proto

Could someone point me where I am going wrong?

Thanks a ton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably these lines:

```
var dec = builder.build("Game");
var msg = dec.decode(messagegpb);
```

Need to be:

```
var Game = builder.build("Game");
var msg = Game.Cars.Car.decode(messagegpb);
```

That is, you need to specify what type you're decoding.

Probably your attempt to call `dec.decode` was throwing an exception saying the `decode` method didn't exist. You should have been able to see these exceptions on the error console, or caught them with `try`/`catch`.

Comment: Thank you very much Kenton. Actually I figured that problem. But now facing a bigger problem. I am able to decode this message but when i receive a message from a websocket which was encoded by a java client, the decoding doesnt work. Any idea about that? Thanks a  lot.

Comment: Basically this is what I am facing now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385865/decoding-a-protocol-buffer-with-javascript